# Genetic Algorithm parameter settings for Real Coded GA

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

is there any suggestion for deciding Genetic Algorithm parameter such as population size, number of generation, crossover rate etc in Real Coded GA?

i m doing my research by using GA to optimize Neural Network parameters.
Since the problems have very large solution spaces and need so many chromosome, so I decided to using Real Coded GA to save computing time.

I found some standart parameter settings such as Dejong Settings (From [DeJong and Spears, 1990]) and Grefenstette Settings (From [Grefenstette, 1986]). But it seems, these parameter settings is just for binary coding..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the best parameters for a Genetic Algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075628/how-to-find-the-best-parameters-for-a-genetic-algorithm)